# grid-row-gap is adding extra height to first (2-row) element in grid layout

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I'm trying to create a simple layout, where I have a grid made up of three rows. I want my first element to take up 2 rows, and the second element to take up the remaining row. That works, but when I introduce a grid-row-gap: 30px;, it seems to add an additional 30px to the height of my first element.

```
<div id="grid">
    <div id="one">1 - height is actually 332px</div>
    <div id="two">2 - height is 150px, which I'd expect</div>
</div>

<style>
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px);
  grid-row-gap: 30px; // the problem with this is that it takes space away from the lower rows, but not the top ones. seeming to add height to the top section
  height: calc(450px + 30px);
  width: 600px;
}

#grid div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3A3A3A;
}

#one {
  grid-row: span 2;
  max-height: 300px;
}
#two {
  grid-row: span 1;
}
</style>
```

I made an example codepen at https://codepen.io/grayayer/pen/xxzQWex

Seems like this should be simpler than it is.

I was expecting the first element to be 300px high, but it's 330px high. The second element is 150px as expected.

Comment: two rows also includes one gap so the result is logical. If you don't want this define 2 rows instead of 3 or use margin instead of gap

Comment: There's no need to use Codepen, use a Stack Snippet instead. (next time)

Answer (score 1):

I've added `box-sizing: border-box;` — perhaps this reduces the confusion? Remember that with the default box-sizing method, the size of your boxes does not include any padding.

https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

But the basic equation is pretty simple: you have two rows which are each 150px high, plus you have a 30px gap between them, so the height of an element which **spans both rows** will be 150px + 30px + 150px = 330px.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 30px;
}

#sponsors_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 150px);
  gap: 30px;
}

#sponsors_grid div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #3A3A3A;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#one {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

#two {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

#three {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#four {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#five {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="sponsors_grid">
    <div id="one">1 - 330px</div>
    <div id="two">2 - 150px</div>
    <div id="three">3 - 150px</div>
    <div id="four">4 - 150px</div>
    <div id="five">5 - 150px</div>
</div>
```